# Streaming Firebase Function logs to a local terminal

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Streaming Firebase Function logs to a local terminal would be very helpful since the Firebase Console web interface for logs is pretty sluggish to work with.

Does any one know a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli), according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#functions-commands), run the command:

```
firebase functions:log
```

This gives you a dump of recent logs, but it doesn't "stream" them to your terminal.  Unfortunately, this is the best you can do.

If you're a gcloud user, there are equivalent commands, as described in its [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs).  There is also no option to stream the logs live with gcloud.

If you want a "live" view of logs of your deployed functions, you're going to have to use the Firebase or Google Cloud console.

If you're doing active development and need the logs for code you've just written, it might be easier to use the [Firebase emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) to run functions locally, so you can see logs appear live in the terminal where the emulator is running.

Comment: Thank you very much for this info, too bad streaming is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new preview feature in GCP logging that allows doing this: [Streaming and live tailing log entries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/streaming-live-tailing)